# Getting data from a .json file in c

Tags: c, json

How do I get information from a JSON file in C? For example the following code in Python

```
open('simfin.json').read()
var = json.loads(open('simfin.json').read())
var = var["var"]
```

Gets the value that I gave to a variable and then stores it in var. How do I do it in C, then write it to the .json file, preferably using Jansson?

Here's my .json file:

```
{
    "whenaddrm": "01/01/1970 00:00",
    "var": 0,
    "moneyaddrm": 0
}
```

Comment: The tutorial of the jansson library looks useful at first glance. Have you tried with  json_loads and then using json_object_get ?

Comment: there are so many json libraries available for C, just choose one and go with it, read the docs. For example you could use https://github.com/json-c/json-c